# isClosed method don't works in JBOSS 5.1

Tags: java, jboss, jtds

I have a method that call a procedure, see:

```
public void myMethod() {    

            ((Session) em.getDelegate()).doWork(new Work() {

                @Override
                public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {

                    StringBuilder sqlSP = new StringBuilder();

                    sqlSP.append("{ call myprocedure ");
                    sqlSP.append("(?) }");

                    CallableStatement cs = connection.prepareCall(sqlSP.toString());                    

                    cs.setInt(1, 1);

                    try {
                        cs.execute();
                    } finally {
                        if (!cs.isClosed()) {
                            cs.close();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
    }
```

This works very well in tomcat, because method isClosed() exists. But when i upload my application to jboss 5.1 i got following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsCallableStatement.isClosed()Z
    at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.jdk6.WrappedCallableStatementJDK6.isClosed(WrappedCallableStatementJDK6.java:64)
```

My tomcat and jboss, both use jTDS 1.2.5, so i can't understand what is the problem. I tried to debug jboss with WrappedCallableStatement but when i try to inspect line "cs.isClosed" i got nestedException.

Comment: Why not just close without checking? The documentation says *Calling the method `close` on a `Statement` object that is already closed has no effect*. So if it's open, it will be closed, and if it's not, no effect. Also, why not use a try-with-resources construct? It will automatically close the statement.

Comment: @RealSkeptic, i didn't know that just close() method works on already closed object, my fault. I will try that. But i didn't understand the "try-with-resources construct", can you give me example ?

Comment: [Oracle Tutorial about try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)